# Apache server not starting 'Address already in use' ERROR (98)

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, port, bitnami

I've been trying for the past few days to solve this issue in several different ways and got no results.

Below is a copy of all the last commands i ran trying to gather more info about the issue:

> 2019 from 181.167.101.245 bitnami@ip-172-31-2-74:~$ sudo service
>   apache2 restart
>   * Restarting web server apache2
>   (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to
>   address [::]:8
>   0
>   (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to
>   address 0.0.0.
>   0:80
>   no listening sockets available, shutting down 
>   AH00015: Unable to open logs
>   Action 'start' failed. 
>   The Apache error log may have more information.                                                                      > [fail] 
>   * The apache2 instance did not start within 20 seconds.
>   Please read the log files to discover problems
>   bitnami@ip-172-31-2-74:~$ sudo netstat -nlp |
>   grep 80
>   tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*
>   LISTEN
>   13456/httpd.bin unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     1680
>   402/systemd-udevd   /run/udev/control

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated and let me know if additional information is needed.

As always thanks in advance.

Comment: "address already in use", you must have something already running on the port you have apache configured - port 80 accoriding to the error messages...-.

Comment: What are you running Windows or Linux?

Comment: Given you are actually connecting to linux with a shell see this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9252/determining-what-process-is-bound-to-a-port?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here,

If you are using a Bitnami ready-to-use instance with any of our applications, they usually include Apache to serve the application. In case you perform any change in the Apache's configuration files inside the /opt/bitnami directory, you need to restart the Apache's service by using the ctlscript.sh file we provide.

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh
```

You can learn more about it here:

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/administration/control-services/

Comment: Jota thanks for your response, i ran the command you provided and the result was sucessful but apache is still not working.

bitnami@ip-172-31-2-74:~$ sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
Unmonitored apache
Syntax OK
/opt/bitnami/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd stopped
Syntax OK
/opt/bitnami/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd started at port 80
Monitored apache

bitnami@ip-172-31-2-74:~$ service apache2 status   * apache2 is not running

Comment: bitnami@ip-172-31-2-74:~$ sudo service apache2 start
 * Starting web server apache2                                                  (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
 *
 * The apache2 instance did not start within 20 seconds. Please read the log files to discover problems

Comment: i thinking of changing the ports in the conf files, do you think that would help solve my problem?

Comment: Hi Minnen, the output of the ctlscript.sh file showed that Apache was started properly. The Bitnami solutions don't use the system's packages so you can't use `sudo service apache2` to manage that service. If you run the ctlscript.sh script again using the status command, it will show the status of the services. `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status`. If Apache is running, you could access your site by accessing the public IP of your instance in the browser.